# Server does not connect to remote machine (Linux)

Tags: linux, c, sockets

I've been having a problem where I am not able to connect two servers together using this simple server i wrote in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "hacking.h"

#define PORT 7890  // the port users will be connecting to

int main(void) {
        int sockfd, new_sockfd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
        struct sockaddr_in host_addr, client_addr;      // my address   information
        socklen_t sin_size;
        int recv_length=1, yes=1;
        char buffer[1024];

        if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
                fatal("in socket");

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
                fatal("setting socket option SO_REUSEADDR");

        host_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;          // host byte order
        host_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);        // short, network byte    order
        host_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // automatically fill with my IP
        memset(&(host_addr.sin_zero), '\0', 8); // zero the rest of the struct

        if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
                fatal("binding to socket");

        if (listen(sockfd, 5) == -1)
                fatal("listening on socket");

        while(1) {    // Accept loop
                sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                new_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &sin_size);
                if(new_sockfd == -1)
                        fatal("accepting connection");
                printf("server: got connection from %s port   %d\n",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
                send(new_sockfd, "Hello World!\n", 13, 0);
                recv_length = recv(new_sockfd, &buffer, 1024, 0);
                while(recv_length > 0) {
                        printf("RECV: %d bytes\n", recv_length);
                        dump(buffer, recv_length);
                        recv_length = recv(new_sockfd, &buffer, 1024,  0);
                }
                close(new_sockfd);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

When I run this code on server A by executing the following commands:

```
gcc simple_server.c
./a.out
```

and

```
telnet 172.31.**.*** 7890
```

on server B, all I get is

```
Trying 172.31.**.***...
```

What might I be doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a route between server A and server B (e.g. can you ping or tracetoute)?  Are there any firewall rules (either on the servers or on any routers in between them) that would block port 7890 connections?

Comment: As you didn't describe your network topology, I'd suggest to make sure e.g. port forwarding on router. And the firewall inside the machine must accept the connection too, of course. Please edit your question for us to know.

Comment: replace your server by eg `nc -l -p 7890` and see if your telnet works. If not, fix your firewall. Compile your server with `-Wall` and fix all warnings. Compile with `-g` and run with `gdb` so you can see what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the firewall on your server A
It is trying to connect the server but the packets keep dropping due to firewall rule

run the below command for list of firewall rules

**iptables -L**

then run the below command to add rule for port 7890

**iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 7890 -j ACCEPT**

if this doesn't work then check if the router in between are droping packets